# Error message when I try to record audio on Anki on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, anki

I get this error message when I try to record audio on Anki desktop on Ubuntu. Anyone knows what might be the problem. My microphone is working fine.

```
Error
An error occurred. Please use Tools > Check Database to see if that fixes the problem.
If problems persist, please report the problem on our support site. Please copy and paste the information below into your report.
Anki 2.1.40 (cf446733) Python 3.8.1 Qt 5.15.1 PyQt 5.15.1
Platform: Linux
Flags: frz=True ao=False sv=1
Add-ons, last update check: 2021-02-17 15:21:54

Caught exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aqt/sound.py", line 475, in _encode_mp3
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lame'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aqt/taskman.py", line 87, in _on_closures_pending
  File "aqt/taskman.py", line 59, in <lambda>
  File "aqt/sound.py", line 489, in _on_done
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
  File "concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
  File "aqt/sound.py", line 492, in <lambda>
  File "aqt/sound.py", line 477, in _encode_mp3
Exception: lameError running ⁨ ⁩/tmp/anki_temp/rec.wavError running ⁨ ⁩/tmp/anki_temp/rec1613573533.mp3Error running ⁨ ⁩--noreplaygainError running ⁨ ⁩--quiet
```

Comment: Do you have Lame installed on your computer? If not, `sudo apt install lame` may resolve your issue 

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. Thank you!